# How would I translate "与君知"

Tags: translation, meaning, classical-chinese

Google translate his been giving me straight pinyin as a translation, and pleco doesn't have what I'm looking for. I got the definitions of each individual character, but I'm not sure how to put them together to make them sounds good. If there's not a smooth translation for this title, would it be better to keep it in pinyin?

It's the name of a song.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Exchange :) would you mind posting precisely what translations for each individual character you've already looked up, and where you found such translations?

Answer (score 1):

My translation would be something like **"With your knowledge"** with the understanding that "your" refers to somebody of a higher status, usually either due to them being royalty or them being immensely respected and of a good moral character (or both!).

To explain, 与 means "with" or "and," a meaning that has not changed much since ancient times. You see it a lot in formal writing, and even in some jargon (e.g. 与门 refers to the AND gate of a logical circuit). In this particular context, it is clear that it probably means "with" as it appears to be a preposition more than a conjunction.

In classical Chinese (文言文), one typically finds the usage of 君 to mean roughly the same as 您 i.e. a polite, honorific pronoun to address somebody of a higher status.

From [有道词典](https://www.youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%90%9B/#keyfrom=dict2.index)：

> 封建时代指帝王、诸侯等，引申为人的尊称，相当于“您”。道德品行良好的人也可称君子。

which, roughly translated, means that during feudal times, 君 referred to kings, princes etc, and others would use it to respectfully address them, equivalent to today's 您. The word 君子 can also be used to refer to somebody with high moral standards and good character.

知 refers to knowledge. You may be familiar with the term 知道 in modern Chinese which means "to know."

Answer (score 1):

My spin:

与君知
What I wanna tell you
What I want you to know
What I need you to know

难得君心知我心
Hard to get your heart to know my heart (probably where the title comes from)
我愿抱着你
I wanna hold you
献尽我热吻
give you my hot kisses

I've got stop, I'm going all gooey!!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a name of a song, I think my answer must be correct. Literally, the meaning is "let you know", has very similar meaning with "让你知道"， and it is a classical Chinese style phrase. "与君知" is more classical, more romantic, and more formal in classical Chinese than "让你知道". most of the time, it shows what a woman wants to say to a man she loves. In classical Chinese, 与 is similar with "let" , 君 is similar with "you" (must be a male), and 知 is similar with "know".

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this, I've figured out a translation for the song, the translation being "For you to know". It fits perfectly given the what the song is describing.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a classical way of saying -- "FYI" -- "For Your Information"

Answer (score 0):

means `Let you know`

actually this sentence is ancient chinese. and mostly occured in song lyric in nowadays.